# How to get file content from post rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, amazon-s3

I have a client in java that sends form post requests with video file.

I get in the server following POST:

```
Parameters: {"video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f26783b49d0 
@original_filename="video", @content_type=nil, 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\"; filename=\"video\"\r\n", 
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160405-3-106c9nr>>, "id"=>"36"}
```

I am trying to save the file to s3 using following lines:
I know the connection and actual saving works because I tried with base64 string as parameter and it worked well.

```
body = params[:video].tempfile
video_temp_file = write_to_file(body)
VideoUploader.new.upload_video_to_s3(video_temp_file, params[:id].to_s+'.mp4')
```

I see on s3 empty files or 24 bytes.
where do i do wrong?

Edit: I am using carrierwave:

```
def write_to_file(content)
  thumbnail_file = Tempfile.new(['video','.mp4'])
  thumbnail_file.binmode # note that the tempfile must be in binary mode
  thumbnail_file.write content
  thumbnail_file.rewind
  thumbnail_file
end
```

Comment: maybe post your `write_to_file` method too.

Comment: Found a post that answered me perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521053/how-to-read-a-user-uploaded-file-without-saving-it-to-the-database