# ------WebKitFormBoundary being added by AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, ruby, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I built a Ruby/Sinatra backend for an angularjs app. I wrote a POST call to parse and upload a file from the request body to AWS S3. Now when I use Postman to upload a file. It works completely fine, the file gets uploaded and I can view it on S3. But the problem is that when I try to upload a file using the angular app, it adds the following to the file cause of which the file gets corrupted and a pdf file opens up as a text file within the browser.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryuRzuSgC6oXxEgwa1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Application Form.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

***FILE DATA HERE***

------WebKitFormBoundaryuRzuSgC6oXxEgwa1--
```

Can someone help me to either parse this data properly in the ruby or help me to avoid adding this extra code from the angular app.

This is the angular code to upload the file

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(files, errFiles) {
      $scope.all_files.push(files);
      console.log($scope.all_files[0]);
       $scope.files = files;
       $scope.errFiles = errFiles;
       angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
           file.upload = Upload.upload({
               url: 'http://api.company.com/upload',
               data: {file: file}
           });

           file.upload.then(function (response) {
               $timeout(function () {
                   file.result = response.data;
               });
           }, function (response) {
               if (response.status > 0)
                   $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
           }, function (evt) {
               file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                        evt.loaded / evt.total));
           });
       });
   };
```

And the following is the code in Ruby to parse and upload the file

```
post '/upload' do
  request.body.rewind
  body = request.body.read
  res(200, {url: saveFile(body)})
end

def saveFile(body)
  name = "random string here"
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'ap-southeast-1')
  obj = s3.bucket('company-files').object(name)
  obj.put(body: body, acl:'public-read')
  saved_url = obj.public_url
  return saved_url
end
```

Comment: The incoming post body is not the raw file, it's a `multipart/form-data` HTTP form post.  You should be able to access the file content with something similar to `params[:file]` based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2521135/1695906).  (I'm basing this on general knowledge of web services.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks man, although I had to use params[:file][:tempfile] to make it work. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to manually set the Content-Type header to force your browser to use this upload mechanism, probably at this point:

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
               url: 'http://api.company.com/upload',
               data: {file: file}
           });
```

I don't know what's Upload object, so I can't say how to do it