# What's the simplest way to upload an image to an application with a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to simply add an image file (or I guess any type of file) to my "app/assets/images" folder, using a form in my app. Paperclip works great for this, but I feel like its unnecessarily complicated for such a simple task. Is there a way to do this built into Rails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read a User uploaded file, without saving it to the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521053/how-to-read-a-user-uploaded-file-without-saving-it-to-the-database)