# How to upload a photo from a Rails cache hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activestorage, wicked-gem, session-cache

I'm quite new with Rails and I'm trying to implement a multistep form in my app for creating a new instance of my `User` model (`devise` gem).

I use `wicked` gem and I've chosen a cache persistence and an ID/Key-in-Session as strategies to handle it.

For now, everything works well until I come across the `avatar` step in my form which is my last one (a `@user` `has_one_attached :avatar`).

When I try to submit my form, I got the below issue raising from that line: `Rails.cache.write(session.id, user_attrs)`

```
TypeError in Users::UserStepsController#update
can't dump File
```

Here my `user_attrs` when I submit my picture:

```
{"messenger_id"=>"1234567890123456",
"form_step"=>:profile_picture_step,
"first_name"=>"John",
"last_name"=>"Doe",
"email"=>"john@gmail.com",
"password"=>"1234",
"password_confirmation"=>"1234",
"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fbdc4cdf418
  @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/m_/8ln6gczs1ns1gnn53p6vskwr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20210527-5416-uy59kl.png>,
  @original_filename="Screenshot 2021-05-26 at 20.34.43.png", @content_type="image/png",
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"Screenshot 2021-05-26 at 20.34.43.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
```

It seems `Rails.cache.write` is not able to write this avatar object, am I right? If so, is there a way to fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you want to read the file and save it's contents (are you sure you want to save that into your cache? if its memory cache it can get bloated pretty fast). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521053/how-to-read-a-user-uploaded-file-without-saving-it-to-the-database

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JoelBlum! You must be right, I will investigate it.

Comment: ActiveStorage can do direct uploads from the client straight up to a cloud service such as S3. You just add the JS to assets/packs and then add  `direct_upload: true ` to the input: `<%= form.file_field :avatar,  direct_upload: true %>`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, I will have a look on this resource. Thanks max